# PHP and MySQL, Query works in one not the other

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query that works in phpMyAdmin but not when being run through php

This is the query:

```
DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ( SELECT * FROM 'table' ORDER BY scoreDESC LIMIT 10 ) foo)
```

Basically, it sorts the table to score descending and then keeps the top 10 and deletes the rest.
I can run this fine trough phpmyadmin but my php code says no

This is the php script:

```
function add_highscore()
{

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM highscores WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ( SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ) foo)")
    or die('0');

    echo "1";

    mysql_close($table_id);
}
```

There is no problems with the connection, I have more functions in the script that works.

Any ideas? 
Help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers, Jon

Comment: Why is `mysql_close` present when you're using `mysqli`?

Comment: Maybe check `mysqli_error`?

Comment: @tadman Perhaps a typo?

Comment: What is the PHP error message ? There is no problem with your query

Comment: Identifiers (like table/field names) should be in backticks (or double quotes in ANSI mode), if you use them.  Single-quoted words are *values*.  I'm rather shocked your query worked in myadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And replace:

```
die('0');
```

with:

```
die(mysql_error());
```

and that should help indicate just what variety of 'not working' the script is.

Comment: Thank you!!! Oh god i've been wtrying to fix this one for a long time. With error reporting (dont know how I could not priorities that) it became very clear that my mysql user didnt have permission to do delete. :)

Thanks again!

Comment: @JonNyström is you question solved by sammitch answer? Please accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

May be function is not being called or connection not established.You should try mysql_error for catching error or use try catch to catch error

Comment: Sory, the php-code isn't correct up in my post. It should say "mysql_query" not "mysqli_multi_query". The mysqli was one of my tries to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
function add_highscore()
{
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    $query = "DELETE FROM highscores WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT (id) FROM ( SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ) foo)";
    mysqli_query($link, $query)    or die('0');

    echo "1";

    mysqli_close($table_id);
}
?>
```

The MYSQL version

```
<?PHP
function add_highscore()
{

    $link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $link);

    $query = "DELETE FROM highscores WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM ( SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 ) foo)";
    return mysql_query($query)   or die('0');

    echo "1";

    mysql_close($link);
}

?>
```

Comment: Doesnt work, the mysqli_query was a typo in my OP. I use mysql_query.

Comment: stop using MYSQL it will be depreciated from version 5.5 onwards.

Comment: @JonNyström this query is not the same as the one in your PHP code. DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ( SELECT * FROM 'table' ORDER BY scoreDESC LIMIT 10 ) foo). Furhermore, you are using quote instead of backticks so I suspect this doesn't work in the command line.

Comment: I got it fixed. A permission problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonNyström great good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an ORM library, it's more easy to work with queries and it's more safety

For example: [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/)

or 
[Search on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)